# Help with an np-completeness proof

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-hardness, np

I know that graph contractability is NP-complete: given $G=(V_1,E_1)$ and $H=(V_2,E_2)$, can a graph isomorphic to $H$ be obtained from $G$ by a sequence of edge contractions?

Consider the following variant of the contractibility problem.  Each node in the input graph is labeled with a unique bit-string of arbitrary length.  The similarity of two nodes is defined to be the length of the longest common prefix of their labels; the weight of an edge is the similarity between its endpoints.  At each step, we are allowed contract any *maximum*-weight edge $(u,v)$ and label the new node with the longest common prefix of the labels of $u$ and $v$.  (There may be several maximum-weight edges.)  However, we must also preserve label uniqueness; if some other node already has the new label, we cannot contract the edge $(u,v)$.  Our goal is to *minimize* the total length of the node labels.

**Are the following problems NP-hard?**

- **Given a labeled graph $G$, find a sequence of legal contractions that minimizes the total length of all node labels in the resulting graph.**
- **Given two labeled graphs $G$ and $H$, is there a sequence of legal contractions that transforms $G$ into $H$?**

Comment: could you define the problem more precisely? like give input and desired output?

Comment: Is H a graph?  Is it part of the input?  What does "the sum of the metrics" mean?  (Under their usual definition, metrics are not numbers.)  Without a precise description HOW the metrics are updated, I don't think this question can be answered even in principle.

Comment: I added more descriptions in bold fonts. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: Edited for clarity (I hope).

Comment: Simultaneously posted on [math.SE (and migrated to CS.SE)](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/np-completeness-proof).    Please don't do that.

Comment: It appears that you have crossposted this question *simultaneously*. While we don't mind a question being reposted, our [site policy](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/231/) only permits a repost after sufficient time has passed and you have not obtained the desired answer elsewhere. I am closing the question since simultaneous crossposting duplicates effort and fractures discussion. Please wait a few days and then if your question is still not answered request a reopening by flagging the question for moderator attention (after summarizing relevant discussions from other sites).